# How to isolate click event on React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have research this for quite a while, but was not able to find a solution. I have a fontawesome arrow toggle in couple of buttons, and I am trying to get them to toggle. the toggle is working, but they are all toggling at the same time. How can I isolate it to the clicked component only?

My example is massive, but I added these buttons, which pretty much has the same functionality ... so in this example, I would like just the clicked button to switch the start/stop text.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isActive : false
    }
  }

  toggleState() {
    this.setState({isActive:!this.state.isActive});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
         <button className={this.state.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'} onClick ={this.toggleState}>{this.state.isActive ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
         <button className={this.state.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'} onClick ={this.toggleState}>{this.state.isActive ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
         <button className={this.state.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'} onClick ={this.toggleState}>{this.state.isActive ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You only have a single `Button` element in your React tree, and there's only exactly one variable storing the state. Then you add three `button` elements that all do the exact same thing: toggle the single `Button`'s state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is, you are using single `state` variable to control all the buttons. Instead of that use an `array`, each value of `array` will be for specific button. To toggle the status of button inside `toggleState` function, pass the index also and use that index to toggle specific item.

Like this:

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         isActive : []
      }
  }
  
  toggleState(i) {
      let isActive = [...this.state.isActive];
      isActive[i] = !isActive[i];
      this.setState({isActive});
  }
  
  render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <button onClick = {() => this.toggleState(0)}>{this.state.isActive[0] ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
            <button onClick = {() => this.toggleState(1)}>{this.state.isActive[1] ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
            <button onClick = {() => this.toggleState(2)}>{this.state.isActive[2] ? 'STOP' : 'START'}</button>
        </div>
     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Mayank. I will accept your answer as soon as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: glad, it helped you :)